# Laravel 4 Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was working on my website and I logged out to test it and it gave me this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mom\a\app\views\home.blade.php)
```

Here is my home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('title') Home @stop

@section('content')
    <!-- User signed in -->
    @if(Auth::check())
        <!-- User is not admin -->
        <p>Welcome back, {{ Auth::user()->username }}.</p>
    @else
        <!-- Nothing -->
    @endif


    @if($posts->count())
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <article class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 well well-white home-posts">
                <h2 class="title"><a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h2>
                <hr class="post-break">
                <h4 class="home-content">{{ Markdown::parse(Str::limit($post->body, 300)) }}</h4>
                <div class="post-footer">
                    <ul class="footer-group">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Published {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</li>
                            <li><a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}"> Read more &rarr;</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        @if(Auth::user()->group ==1)
                            <ul class="footer-right">
                                <li class="red"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Edit</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        @else
                            <!-- Nothing -->
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 ">{{ $posts->appends(array())->links() }}</div>
@stop
```

If someone could help me find out what property is of the non object is being called and help me fix it. That would be great. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you need to check $posts, then if it's okay maybe the auth system you've got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this line

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2 ">{{ $posts->appends(array())->links() }}</div>
```

in your if statement

EDIT:

Try to change line:

```
@if(Auth::user()->group ==1)
```

to

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->group ==1)
```